# Throwing an exception when another exception has not been handled yet. (C++)

Tags: c++, exception

As far as I know, throwing an exception when another has not been handled yet is undefined behavior, and the program may crash. An exception is considered unhandled until it gets into the catch-block. I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ThrowingInDestructorClass
{
    public:
    ThrowingInDestructorClass() = default;
    
    ~ThrowingInDestructorClass() { 
        try {
            throw std::runtime_error("2-nd exception. ");
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout << "Catched an error during Throwing class cleanup. " << std::endl;
        };
        
    }
};

void doSmth()
{
    try {
        ThrowingInDestructorClass throwing;
        
        throw std::runtime_error("1-St exception. ");
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Catched an error during doSmth. " << std::endl;
    };
}

int main() {    
    doSmth();
}
```

Here we have a class that can throw and handle an exception inside its destructor, so it is OK. But we have a method that creates objects and throws an exception. During stack-unwinding, the class destructor will be called, throwing a 2-nd exception. So the 1-St exception will be unhandled yet.
When I run it, I get the following output:

```
Caught an error during Throwing class cleanup. 
Caught an error during doSmth.
```

It may seem that everything is fine, but I'm not entirely sure that there is no UB here.
Could someone help to clarify the situation?

Comment: As long as you catch the 2nd exception within the destructor, the destructor isn't seen as having thrown an exception as far as the handling of the first exception is concerned. It returns normally.

Comment: The 2nd execption will only trigger `std::terminate` if it causes stack unwinding by exiting the method (function) where it was thrown. _"...If any function that is called directly by the stack unwinding mechanism, after initialization of the exception object and before the start of the exception handler, __exits with an exception__, std::terminate is called. ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw

Comment: "throwing an exception when another has not been handled yet is undefined behavior". This is not true. Nothing whatsoever about it is undefined. If you throw an exception when another has not been handled yet, *and* you let the second exception escape a destructor that was called in process of handling the first exception, *then* you get a *well-defined* program termination.

Comment: Not **undefined behavior**, q.v. [`std::uncaught_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) may be of interest.

Comment: Don't forget exception handling is scope based. So throws/catches like scopes can be nested.  Throwing an exception while there is still an uncaught exception will call terminate and exit your program and this is defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is mostly just a summary of the comments:
I'll go through the program step by step starting at the point the first exception is thrown:

1. Stack unwinding begins by destroying the "throwing" object.
2. The destructor of the "throwing" object gets called, throwing another exception.
3. Stack unwinding finds a catch block for the new exception immediately, handling the exception. The destructor exits normally.
4. The stack unwinding finds the catch block for the first exception, handling it.
5. doSmth() exits normally

No function exited with an exception, thereby the condition

> "...If any function that is called directly by the stack unwinding mechanism, after initialization of the exception object and before the start of the exception handler, **exits with an exception**, std::terminate is called. ..." [en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) - Richard Critten

isn't met.

And even if you remove the try catch in the destructor, no UB will occur:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ThrowingInDestructorClass
{
    public:
    ThrowingInDestructorClass() = default;

    ~ThrowingInDestructorClass() { 
        throw std::runtime_error("2-nd exception. ");
    }
};

void doSmth()
{
    try {
        ThrowingInDestructorClass throwing;
    
        throw std::runtime_error("1-St exception. ");
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Catched an error during doSmth. " << std::endl;
    };
}

int main() {    
    doSmth();
}
```

This program will crash because std::terminate is called when stack unwinding (as now a function exits with an exception).

> If you throw an exception when another has not been handled yet, and you let the second exception escape a destructor that was called in process of handling the first exception, *then* you get a *well-defined* program termination. –
> n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.

Your program will crash, but that crash is not UB but well-defined behaviour